# "Home" of other people

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to use the word "**home**" to refer to other people's places they live in?

- I stayed at my friend's home all night yesterday.
- My parent's home is where I usually go for the weekends.
- We'll visit my Grandma's home tomorrow.

It seems a little bit odd to me.

Comment: Perfectly fine. The possessive forms of friend, parent, and Grandma modify home to indicate whose home it is.

Comment: I agree that it's fine.  I think people are more likely to say "friend's house" (Google Ngram says it's about six times more frequent than "friend's home"), but using "home" is perhaps better if your friend lives in an apartment rather than in a stand-alone house.

Comment: I would qualify further where ambiguous:  apartment, house, tent or whatever, Grandma's home would likely be the old people's home where she has a room - you might not even go see your Grandma. _We'll visit my Grandma's home tomorrow. I have some things to discuss with the manager_

Comment: @CanadianYankee - If my friend lived in an apartment, I might be inclined to say "at my friend's apartment." I agree that it's not "ungrammatical", but the first one does sound a little odd to me.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I'm most used to hearing "at my friend's _place_" if it's unimportant whether the friend lives in a house/apartment/trailer/whatever.  Sometimes the noun is elided altogether: "We'll visit my Grandma's tomorrow," although that's pretty colloquial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine as long as you are aware that a "house" is not necessarily a "home", and vice-versa.  A *house* is a physical structure, but a *home* is where you live (or, proverbially, where you "hang your hat").

> My grandmother's **home** is a small apartment overlooking Main street.
>
> My grandmother's **house** is at the end of a long, tree-lined lane.

For whatever reason English speakers are much more likely to use "a friend's house" than "a friend's home".  For example, it's much more invasive to say

> I walked into my friend's **home** uninvited.

than it is to say

> I walked into my friend's **house** uninvited.

In the same way, it's more personal to refer to your own place of residence as your *home*, rather than your *house*.

> Why don't you come over to our **home** for dinner tonight?

In some contexts this might feel like *too much*, and "house" is preferable to main a comfortable distance.  This, of course, varies greatly by culture and personality.